# How to fix repeated freezes and crashes in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS?

Tags: boot, uefi, firefox, freeze, crash

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a new Lenovo Ideapad 3 17IRU7 with 8 GB memory. I'm experiencing two types of crashes repeatedly every day:  Libre Office crashes when I use Alt-Tab to switch between screens and sometimes when I am opening other programs or tabs in Firefox.  Firefox freezes and the system crashes, taking me to a login screen, periodically.

I would like to re-install Ubuntu, as I think some packages may be broken, but every method requires a live USB, and the lousy firmware BIOS does not include the option to boot from USB, nor can I edit options (there is not Advanced option in the BIOS/UEFI).  I originally installed from Windows, but accidentally wiped out Windows using the Manual option in disk partitioning.

Comment: Fixed this -- sort of -- by uninstalling and reinstalling Libre Office.  No more crashes on that account.  But Firefox continues to periodically freeze.